# Obligating a client to set a JFrame's size, before printing onto it

Tags: java, swing

I'm designing a GUI to display a binary search tree. The GUI makes some calculations to position tree nodes on the GUI frame with the call `printer.print(...)`. For example, tree nodes one depth apart from each other have Y coordinates `vGap` apart from each other.
 Some calculations also use `getWidth()`, but `getWidth()` will return 0 if the UI's  size hasn't yet been configured. This fact creates a problem in the following code block that I originally used:

```
myPrinter <Integer> printer = new myPrinter <> (); 
printer.print(tree.root); // HERE
Construct frame = new Construct (printer);

// code to display the JFrame
// code to size the frame
```

***In this block***, the code responsible for drawing the search tree is called with `printer.print(tree.root)`. `printer.print(tree.root)` accesses getWidth() before the width is set, however. Consequently, `printer.print(tree.root)` uses getWidth() as if it were 0.

---

To avoid this problem, I was forced to size my GUI before drawing onto it.

```
Construct frame = new Construct (printer);

// code to display the JFrame
// code to size the frame

myPrinter <Integer> printer = new myPrinter <> (); 
printer.print(tree.root); // HERE
```

If I wanted to let clients use my Printer, I would have to constrain my client's use of `printer.print(tree.root)` to after he or she constructed and sized a GUI frame. Is there a way to contractualize that requirement or altogether abandon its need?

One solution comes to mind: I change `printer.print(someRoot root)` to `printer.print(someRoot root, int frameWidth)`

Are there any other approaches?

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I'm lost as to what your code does. I understand the issue of setting sizes of GUI's, and usually the best solution is to let the layout managers and the components size themselves, sometimes with a nudge by overriding `getPreferredSize()` for a key component, but I'll be darned if I can figure out your code or problem enough to help you implement this. Please consider improving your question and showing more pertinent code, preferably an [mcve]. Assume that we don't know what your code is doing.

Comment: I would use a 5 step approach.  1) Calculate the size of your drawing area by using your hGap and vGap parameters.  2) Create a BufferedImage of the correct size.  3) Draw your diagram on the BufferedImage.  4) Copy your BufferedImage onto a DrawingPanel (JPanel) of a defined size, with a JScrollPane so that the BufferedImage fits on the display.  5) SetVisible your JFrame.